# Java is taking a class from the wrong path

Tags: java, path, project

I have 2 projects: project1 and project2 and the class `Class1` in both projects but there are differences between these classes.

I'm trying to use Project1.Class1 in a XHTML file but sometimes it takes `Project2.Class1`.

I have already checked every import in my classes and everything seems to be alright. Does anyone know why Eclipse is taking the wrong path?.

Comment: Can you add your code? Check project and OS classpath also.

Comment: Wait until Java 9 gets released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem with java. If you have 2 java classes with same name and package structure, the class which is first seen in class path will be loaded in to the memory. The other class will be omitted as per the class loading policy.

If you want use only one class, Keep that class alone in the classpath and remove the other one.